# How to get national holidays of selected country

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I'm writing an app that allows the user to select a country from a list. When they pick a country, a list of national holidays of that country appears.

I've seen [CalendarProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) and [Google Calendar V3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/), but they seem to only provide the current user's calendar.

How can I get the national holidays of a specific country? Any suggestion would help me.

---

Update:

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651017/accessing-google-calendar-api-with-javascript-without-authorization) which can get a list of holidays in JSON format. In this example, the country code is defined by calendar ID, for instance pt_br.brazilian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com or en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com.

But I can't find any documentation about this. Is it possible to use the API this way? If yes, where can I get those calendar IDs?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Problem solved by using [Google Calendar API V3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/). The idea I found from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651017/accessing-google-calendar-api-with-javascript-without-authorization). 
The holiday can get from default holiday calendar of google.

The ID list of default holiday calendar can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mattn/1438183), support to 40 country.

A piece of code that handle permission and get holiday list:-

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client = null;
        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(mContext, CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(mList.get(0));
        client = getCalendarService(credential);
        do {
            com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events events;
            events = client.events().list("en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            onHolidayChecked(events.getItems()); //result return here (events.getItems())
            pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
        } while (pageToken != null);

private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar getCalendarService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
    return new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
}
```

Comment: Its possible to do the same thing with javascript?

Comment: @Vitor Guerreiro It's some kind of google API so I think It's possible

Comment: I am getting this error com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException, I have also looked on google, does this require a google project that link to the app in order to get the data?

Answer (score 3):

The CalendarProvider documentation states that it only provides the current user's calendar information.

> The Calendar Provider is a repository for a user's calendar events.
>   The Calendar Provider API allows you to perform query, insert, update,
>   and delete operations on calendars, events, attendees, reminders, and
>   so on.

You will need to access a third-party API ([this one](http://kayaposoft.com/enrico/), for example) and load that information into your application.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your Holiday API is a paid services, I'll choose something free. Have you tried google calendar V3 ?. I've confused a bit when read their docs

Comment: I'm not experienced with Google Calendar V3. Have a look at this: http://kayaposoft.com/enrico/

Comment: Alright, let me know if this works out for you once you try :)

Comment: thumb up for mentioning example of third party API