# Date Picker android, I want to disable holidays

Tags: android

I want to disable the holidays date in the DatePickerDialog . Please suggest me how could i do this.Here is my code..

```
     dateJourney = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel(inputJReportDate);

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve list of holidays from google api:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048193/1384010

Once you need that list, you just need to disable them in your picker.