# Java check if specific date is public holiday by country

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

In my java application (spring boot), I'm trying to check if a specific date for Malaysia is a public holiday or not and the challenge is each state has its own Regional holidays on top of the national public holidays which has to be considered.

So my question is that can I do such a thing using Google Calendar API?

I've found this  [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996577/how-to-get-national-holidays-of-selected-country) but I'm not sure if that would do what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, did you try? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

I've combined some public resources and I'd do that this way:

You want to call for a calendar with id: `en.malaysia#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com`
Call:
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}`
Authorisation:

> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes (...): `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`

[--Api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get)
[--StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048193/4723795)
[--List of supported national calendars](https://gist.github.com/mattn/1438183)

Comment: ok that cleared some stuff for me but then how can I know which day is public holiday because using the form google has on the Api link you provided it just returns me these fields (kind, etag, id, summary, timeZone)