# Implementing Google Calendar V3 API without signing in the user to Gmail account

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I've been searching for a couple of hours now and i just keep getting even more confused about the subject and so I'd love if someone could clear it out for me.

The Issue - 
**I want to implement the Google Calendar API only for getting holidays events and inserting them into my calendar in the app.
I have no interest in the user's info/personal events and such.**

For the Calendar view im using - https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

And the idea eventually is to show the holidays on that calendar.

I got the direction of how to get the holidays once the API will be implemented as should from the first answer here - 
[How to get national holidays of selected country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996577/how-to-get-national-holidays-of-selected-country)

I've opened a service account in the google developers console but I'm all confused about the next steps.

I would have used a different API because i don't really need all that the google api is giving but they all cost money. If anyone has a good free api for getting a specific religion's holidays that could also come in help.

Thanks.