# Getting JSON with list of national holidays Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

How to get a holiday list of selected country using **Google Calendar** with javascript or jquery?

It's possible? Any suggestion?

I'm working with [Google Calendar API V3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/) and using **javascript**.
I found some examples in android, but I don't know nothing about android.

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996577/how-to-get-national-holidays-of-selected-country

Comment: I need javascript example, not android. @Arius

Comment: Sorry but what is the difference? You are using API in the same way in all languages...

Comment: No, it is not same way. See at: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/. Have many ways to start as differents languages.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/ - this is just REST API to consume. Despite the differences of conusming API like this in different languages, you will ALWAYS ask the same endpoints with the same results no matter what language you will use.  You can just use $.ajax() call from jQuery to receive results.

Comment: you could solve it programmatic using the 'Easter Algorithm':
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896954/decoding-gauss-easter-algorithm

Comment: Anyway @VitorGuerreiro  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651017/accessing-google-calendar-api-with-javascript-without-authorization

Comment: None of these answers shows what I need, I will keep trying here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple example with a handful of the [public holidays calendars](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#settings-dir_10%7Choliday):

```js
$("#selectCountry").change(function(e) {
  $("#output").html("Loading...");
  var country = $("#selectCountry").val();
  var calendarUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.' + country 
                  + '%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=<yourAPIKey>';

  $.getJSON(calendarUrl)
    .success(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
      $("#output").empty();
      for (item in data.items) {
        $("#output").append(
          "<hr><h3>" + data.items[item].summary + "<h3>" +
          "<h4>" + data.items[item].start.date + "<h4>"
        );
      }
    })
    .error(function(error) {
      $("#output").html("An error occurred.");
    })
});
$("#selectCountry").trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <select id="selectCountry">
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    <option value="uk">UK</option>
    <option value="bm">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="swedish">Sweden</option>
  </select>
  <pre id="output"></pre>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>
```

This strategy constructs a URL for the calendar from the option selected in the dropdown menu. It parses the holiday name and information from the raw JSON response, which is contained in the `data` parameter of the `$.getJSON` callback function.

Comment: Yes, the [V2 interface was deprecated](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample) in November of 2014, and my original answer used that interface. I've updated the answer to use the V3 interface, but note that this requires you to use an [API key as detailed in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27213635/1612562). Just replace `<yourAPIKey>` in the code above with a valid browser API key.

Comment: how i will get the data year wise

Comment: This doesn't work for all the countries, try TR, DE, FR and you will get an error